# Getting HTTP 431 error while making a call to REST URI - Intermittently

Tags: java, rest, http, jetty

While making a call from the browser to my server which is running on AWS, on Jetty server I get below error

```
Request URL: https://test.apps.xxx.com/api/someURI
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 431 431
Remote Address: XXX:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 05:09:59 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
l5d-success-class: 1.0
Server: nginx/1.15.5
Set-Cookie: TFCTESTSID=XXX
Sprox-Request-Id: LQJE78gYarKOiS4CUJed
Via: 1.1 linkerd, 1.1 linkerd
Via: 1.1 test.apps.xxx.com
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 498
content-Type: application/json
Cookie: s_vi=XXX
Host: test.apps.xxx.com
Origin: https://test.apps.xxx.com
Referer: https://test.apps.xxx.com/apps/xxx/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
{,…}
XXX: "XXX"
species: "human"
primaryEditType: "TagN"
primaryEditSite: 154
primaryEditSequence: ""
primaryReplacementStringLength: 0
secondaryReplacementStringLength: 0
numberOfEdits: 1
```

Same payload for the same server worked after a minute. I have seen this error for other API calls as well where the payload is very small.

Upon googling, I could see that this is because of "header fields are too large". This does not justify why it works after a minute.

Why do we see such Intermittent behaviour ?

Backend Server : Running on Jetty.

Call made from browser using HTML and Javascript.

Browser : Chrome (Have not tested it on other browsers though )

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in the server logs? what are the total header sizes of the requests that get the 431 response compared to the ones that do work correctly? You can check or modify the max HTTP header size through the Jetty HttpConfiguration, however it may not be the best solution to increase this over 8k which seems to be the standard.

Comment: The only log I see is this 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-24 02:07:17.834+0000 [qtp1900164709-12] WARN [HttpParser] bad HTTP parsed: 431 for HttpChannelOverHttp@73539ba7{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The same request works in the next few seconds. So I have not tested the header size.

Comment: What version of Jetty are you on? that log looks like its from an older version, you should probably upgrade to 9.4 if you're not using that. Then you could compare the requests on the server side which don't give a 431 to the ones that do and see what the difference is.